# Django two types of users, profile permission for owner or second type

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django REST api, I have two types of users, `provider` and `consumer`, each is one-to-one linked with `user` object from `django.contrib.auth`. I want to make the `consumer` profiles available to all `provider` users to read but not to `consumer` users. The only `consumer` to read the profile is the owner, who should be able to edit it too.

I want to make a permission class

```
class ConsumerProfilePermission(BasePermission):
'''
if provider -> read only
if owner or admin -> full access
if other consumer -> permission denied
'''
```

so I won't have to check the permission in the view. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use object_permission level. I think this should work:

```
class ConsumerProfilePermission(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, profile):
          if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                // Your Instance of profile must have an attribute named `owner` or replace it with the respective attribute.
                return (request.user.is_provider) or (request.user == profile.owner) or request.user.is_staff
          else:
                return request.user == profile.owner or request.user.is_staff
```

If you use generic views, then they will check the appropriate object level permissions, but if you're writing your own custom views, you'll need to make sure you check the object level permission checks yourself. here in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) explain this